I have an attribute with char and I need only numbers
I have an attribute in Nifi with this value: CHAA001962
I need only 001962.How can I do this?

If it is going to always be of a certain format ABCD123456 you could use a regexp to get the 2nd value and save that to an attribute.

Use can try execute stream command by using linux cmd tr in the command path and use command arguments as  [a-zA-Z];"" and argument delemiter as ;
